# Recursive Unzip From Linux Shell?

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu, zip, unzip

I have a file named `'mainZip.zip'`'

This file (`'mainZip.zip'`') contains two files:

`'textFile.txt'`

`'secondaryZip.zip'`

---

`'secondaryZip.zip'` file contains two files as well:

`'apple.bin'`

`'cat.jpg'`

---

Can you advise how to unzip `'cat.jpg'` in one bash command?  can this be done using 'unzip' only?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

[Here](http://www.dbforums.com/unix-shell-scripts/1619154-how-unzip-files-recursively.html) is someone's answer to this exact question, using a custom script. It appears that Unix does not have a built-in recursive unzip option

Comment: The Link doesn't seem to work anymore. Please explain solutions in the answer.

Comment: @Alex Indeed, my younger self should have done so. I'll try to recover the information then flesh out this answer.

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
unzip mainZip.zip && unzip secondaryZip.zip
```

Comment: True, but the example doesn't really indicate recursive. Truly recursive will require some more elaborate script.

Comment: Keith: thank you, yet this solution unzips both files, while I was interested to unzip just `'cat.jpg'` from file `'secondaryZip.zip'`